Empty iterator when using TaskGroup with Motor Aggregate
I am receiving StopIteration error when iterating over the result of an aggregate using TaskGroups, but not otherwise. I have created a minimal example to show the error:
import asyncio

from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient


def create_aggregate():
    client = AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    collection = client["test"]["test"]

    return collection.aggregate([])

async def get_next(agg):
    item = await agg.next()
    print(item)

async def run_1_success():
    agg = create_aggregate()
    
    await get_next(agg)

async def run_2_success():
    agg = create_aggregate()
    await get_next(agg)

    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(get_next(agg))
        tg.create_task(get_next(agg))

async def run_3_error():
    agg = create_aggregate()

    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        tg.create_task(get_next(agg))
        tg.create_task(get_next(agg))

When running asyncio.run(run_1_success()) or asyncio.run(run_2_success()) I can successfully iterate over the trivial aggregation, even using TaskGroup. But when running asyncio.run(run_3_error()) I receive a StopAsyncIteration error.
Environment:

Python 3.12.2 (tags/v3.12.2:6abddd9, Feb  6 2024, 21:26:36) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)]
Motor 3.4.0
PyMongo 4.6.2
Windows 10 64 bit.

Thank you.

From the docs, for MotorCollection.aggregate, emphasis mine:

Note that this method returns a  MotorCommandCursor  which lazily runs the aggregate command when first iterated. In order to run an aggregation with  $out  or  $merge the application needs to iterate the cursor.

In run_2_success, there is an initial await get_next(agg), which executes the aggregation and waits until the cursor is returned. So the cursor is available to be iterated over in the TaskGroups with block.
But in run_3_error, since both tasks have the same agg aggregation object, it is not ready for next - while the first one is still waiting for the cursor to be returned and the second one is already trying to iterate over the cursor (or vice-versa as the tasks execute).
If I add a await asyncio.sleep(1) between the two tasks in run_3_error, then it works.
Also, you don't need a get_next(agg) method. The MotorCollection.aggregate object

Returns a  MotorCommandCursor  that can be iterated like a cursor from  find():

Side note: You should not be trying to iterate over the results of one cursor in parallel. If you want to do something asynchronously with the results, it should be something like:
async def do_something(res):
    print(f"doing something with: {res["item"]}")
    await asyncio.sleep(.1)
    print(f"done with: {res["item"]}")


async def run_4_okay():
    agg = create_aggregate()
    
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        async for result in agg:
            tg.create_task(do_something(result))

(Append those to a tasks list to track results later)
Output, using this MongoDB docs collection :
doing something with: notebook
doing something with: paper
doing something with: postcard
done with: paper
done with: postcard
done with: notebook


Thank you. Why is it better to just iterate over one cursor in parallel? I was trying this approach because this code is part of a bigger library, which passes the iterator to each task, instead of iterating the iterator and passing each item to the tasks.

You're not gaining much by parallel iteration. Once you get the results, "what you do with the results" is what should be separate tasks. And they will all run in parallel. If you really want to iterate in parallel, how many workers will you create? If there are 1000 results and you get 100 at a time, you need to manually add 10 rows of tg.create_task(get_next(agg)). What if there are 2000 results? Will you make that 20 rows? What about 1850 results? That needs 19 lines: 18 will get 100 each and the 19th wil get 50. As you can see, this won't actually work.

Each group of 100 results should be made into an async task. Also, if you iterate with the same cursor in 20 tasks, you're making 20 requests to Mongo, which is going to go over it sequentially anyway, it can't "slice" the results in parallel. So you gain very little by iterating the cursor in parallel. Get results sequentially and create "async tasks with results" to execute in parallel/asynchronously, as I've done in run_4_okay(). (I'm using the word parallel loosely here.)

Wrt "because this code is part of a bigger library" No, that bigger library is wrong. Or you have misunderstood what is required by it. Passing the iterator to each task really means they want to create a fixed number of workers to iterate in parallel. But then you first have to wait for at least one set of results, like you have done in run_2_success(). And remember to create a task which will use that first batch of results also, so modify that outer get_next to something like await asyncio.create_task(get_next(agg)) (before & outside the task groups)
